# Is there a way to upload a folder from the Files app into a computer on the local network?

Tags: ios, network, file-sharing, ftp, files.app

Is there a way to upload a folder from the Files app into a computer on the local network? The only solution I have found is to start an SFTP server on the computer, and use the app Secure Shellfish to expose that SFTP directory in the Files app. This solution is, unfortunately, very slow (maxes out at 9 MB/s in a network that can handle 70 MB/s).

PS: `SMB` barely even works, and is the slowest option ever.

Comment: If the computer is a Mac then it provides a sftp server as part of the OS - just turn remote sharing on - it does both SMB and sftp

Comment: SMB works rather well, usually, not sure why it seems slow in your case

Answer (score 1):

[FE File Explorer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fe-file-explorer-file-manager/id510282524) can do this:

> FE File Explorer is a powerful file manager app on your iPhone and iPad. It can access not only local files, but also files on your computer and NAS. Stream movies and music to your iPhone/iPad. Directly view and manage documents, photos, files on your computers and cloud without downloading to your iPhone/iPad.

1. Add the remote computer's server (I recommend a [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) server)
2. Now add the directories from the Files app you need
3. You can copy stuff between these "remotes" now. Take care not to background the app while the file transfers are ongoing, as iOS sucks and closes all background apps.

I achieved ~63 MB/s using this method.

Comment: Can this app access files in Files?

Comment: @nohillside It can, but the Files app cannot access it IIRC.